# What realization is faster and why

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I wrote a function that calculate this value/formula:

[image: formula]

and I have 2 realizations, and I don't understand, why realization with 3 loops is working faster than realization with if's?

Please, explain to me why is that?

**If's realization:**

```
function res(p, square) {
  let res = 0
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;
  let k = 1;


  label: for (;;) {
    res += (i ** 3 * j ** 2 * k)
    if (k < p) {
      k++
      continue label
    }
    if (j < p) {
      k = 1
      j++
      continue label
    }
    if (i < p) {
      k = 1
      j = 1;
      i++
      continue label
    }
    if (k == p && j == p && i == p) {
      return res
    }
  }
}
```

**Loop realization:**

```
function res1(p) {
  let res = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= p; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= p; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k <= p; k++) {
        res += (i ** 3 * j ** 2 * k)
      }
    }
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: I feel like it's most likely a language thing.  But what is a "realization"?

Comment: I am thinking it is supposed to be "solution"

Comment: "implementation" would be the usual term

Comment: the "three if" implementation checks all three `if` every time. The "three for loop" one, most visibly on the most inner loop, only checks one `if` per iteration (the entire thing checks two `if` every p iterations, and three `if` every p² iterations). `if` is an expensive operation.

Comment: As an additional note, the formula results in `(1/48)*(p**4)*((1 + p)**4)*(1 + 2*p)`, which is obviously insanely much faster to calculate than any for loop construct.

Comment: @ASDFGerte This. (I'd talk of "conditionals" though, or even "conditional jumps"). Please make it an answer.

Comment: I think getting an answer to this is like getting a fish, but looking at JavaScript profiling tool (which is conveniently build in e.g Chrome) is like getting a fishing rod.

Comment: @TeWu or a ticket towards the hell, that is the combination of premature optimization, along with reading the tea leaves of sterile micro-benchmarks. Just always beware, not to measure some execution times, see that one is somewhere within a factor two faster/slower than the other, and then jump to conclusions.

Comment: @Bergi looking at this again, it's actually not as simple as i originally stated - i had the order of the `if` somehow inverted in my mind. Being as-is, the code, simplistically speaking, won't pass the other `if`, while incrementing `k` (will just hit the `continue`). It's a far less pronounced issue than originally thought.